# CakePHP Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, fatal-error

**Hello All**
**I checked all the posts regarding this ERROR.** But my context is little different. Please have a look.

## My Model:-

```
class Post extends AppModel {


    function add($data){
        if (!empty($data)) {
    $this->create();
    if($this->save($data)) {
        return true ; 

        }
    }
 }
    //For Add Action
   function fetchdata() {
        return  $this->find('all',array( 'order' => array('id DESC') ) );   

    }
   //For Edit Action
   function fetch() {
        return  $this->Posts->find('all',array( 'order' => array('id DESC')) ); 

    }

    function getdata($id) {
        return  $this->Posts->find('all',array( 'conditions' => array('id'=>$id)) );    

    }
    //For Index Action
    function retrievedata($id) {
        return  $this->Posts->find('all',array( 'conditions' => array('id'=>$id)) );    

    }
```

}

### Here I am using the EDIT FUNCTION

```
//For Edit Action
   function fetch() {
        return  $this->Posts->find('all',array( 'order' => array('id DESC')) ); 

    }
```

## My Controller:-

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('Post');

public function index(){

    if(isset($this->request->params['pass'][0])){

$this->set('showdata',$this->Post->retrievedata($this->request->params['pass'][0]));
     }

}   

public function add()
 {

         if(!empty($this->request->data)){
        if($this->Post->add($this->request->data)==true){
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
         }

        }
    }

public function edit(){

    $this->set('post',$this->Post->fetch());
    if(isset($this->request->params['pass'][0])){

$this->set('showdata',$this->Post->getdata($this->request->params['pass'][0]));
    }
}
```

}

### The Edit Function is what I am dealing with

```
public function edit(){

    $this->set('post',$this->Post->fetch());
    if(isset($this->request->params['pass'][0])){

   $this->set('showdata',$this->Post->getdata($this->request->params['pass'][0]));
    }
}
```

## Now the ERROR

```
Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
File: C:\wamp\www\blogproject\app\Model\Post.php
Line: 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model name is Post not Posts so change `Posts->find()` to `Post->find()`.
Also for example in `Post->fetch()` your are in Post model scope so use `$this->find()` not $this->Post->find().

Read about [cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions). Model names are singular.

Comment: No its not working... and  Posts->find() shows the table Posts(If I am correct)

Comment: You have "class Post extends AppModel" so your model class is Post not Posts. I've updated my answer. Read about conventions.

Comment: It's Working but giving another error. please check the VIEW <?php foreach($post as $data):?>
   
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($data['Posts']['title'],array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index/'.$data['Posts']['id'].'')) ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php
       $position=200; // Define how many character you want to display.
             $message= $data['Posts']['body'];
       $post = substr($message, 0, $position);
       echo $post;
        ?>
       </td>
    
    </tr>

Comment: the error is Undefined INDEX Posts. What to do here?

Comment: Again. Same thing. $data['Post'] not $data['Posts']. Please read cakephp book.